# Combination of vertical and horizontal table in closedxml.report

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am working on a project and I’m using ClosedXML to document some results in an Excel sheet.

I have the following data structure:

[image: Class Diagramm Switch class]

The PortTag Dictionary is just a Key Value Pair of Port Id and Tag (either “T”, “U”, “F” or “-“)
This should result in a Table that looks like this:

[image: Table as needed]

This is the combination of a vertical and a horizontal version and I’m failing to create it.

My current sheet displays information I polled off of a switch with SNMP and looks as follows:

[image: current sheet]

Is there any help you can offer me or direct me to a source of knowledge regarding this problem?

I already read the information on the Github Wiki and the Website (https://closedxml.github.io/ClosedXML.Report/docs/en/)

thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I. If all `Vlan` entries have the same set of keys

You can use this approach:

1. Define a vertical table `Vlans`
2. Define a horizontal table `PortTag_Values` inside
3. Define another horizontal table `PortTagKeys` where the keys should be placed

[image]

4. In code, add `data` as one variable and `PortTagKeys` as another (note that I ommit checks for null and empty collection for simplicity):

```
var template = new XLTemplate(workbook);
template.AddVariable(data);
template.AddVariable("PortTagKeys", data.Vlans[0].PortTag.Keys);
template.Generate();
```

5. Get what you wanted:
   [image]

### II. If `Vlan` entries may have different sets of keys

In this case, I would suggest performing a pre-processing to get a collection of all keys and to fill all `PortTag`s with the same keys (putting `-` for missing keys). I doubt it is possible to do in "pure" ClosedXML.Report, without pre-processing.

Comment: Alternatively, you can still use pivot tables, the `<<Pivot>>` tag